# The English word "and"

Tags: word-choice

Is it ok to start a sentence with the word "and"? Some of my students are challenging that using "and" at the beginning of a sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean that they are saying that using _and_ at the beginning of a sentence is incorrect? Or do you mean that they are challenging some rule forbidding it, and therefore are saying that it is **not** incorrect?

Comment: See also [Should we not start sentences with And, But, So, or Because](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/561/should-we-not-start-sentences-with-and-but-so-and-because)

Comment: It used not to be alright. At school in Britain, in the 1950s it was heavily discouraged, and attracted the teacher's red pen. But it has become acceptable in recent decades.

Comment: "Some of my students are challenging that using "and" at the beginning of a sentence is incorrect."  And why would that be?

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to use "and" or any conjunction in the beginning of a sentence .

Example: I Don't believe in ghosts! And I will stick to this belief until you show me one!

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely okay for someone to use "And" at the beginning of a sentence, so long as he/she has a good handle of the cadence of the English language.